# Excel export multiple different tables to XML

Tags: excel, export-to-xml

I have an excel (2016) document. On one sheet I have a table that I want to export to XML, no probleem. Now I ad an new sheet with a new and different table, that I also want to export to XML, this doesn't work. Is there a way to make this work?

I using the menu 'Developer'. I added a XML-map. Made the table, with the XML-map. And then I export, with the button 'export' in the menu 'developer'

Comment: How are you exporting to XML, Please can you elaborate your question. I am guessing that the formula or the reference may be missing.

Comment: I using the menu 'Developer'. I added a XML-map. Made the table, with the XML-map. And then I export, with the button 'export' in the menu 'developer'

Comment: I have no idea why but today it works, didn't yesterday. Thanks